# Mocha test script fails to run because of socket.io error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mocha.js

I'm trying to run my tests(mocha) by typing npm run test in my console. It was working yesterday until I pulled down some code my team wrote. For some reason that messed it up. We're writing an app that uses Socket.io and for some reason it shows up in the cmd. Also I'm running this on a PC. Here's the error that it gives me when I do npm run test:

`$ npm run test`

```
> potentpotables@1.0.0 test C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app
> mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test

>C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\url.js:29
  if (null == uri) uri = loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host;
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at url (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\url.js:29:29)
    at lookup (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\socket.io-client\lib\index.js:44:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (sockets_client.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at loader (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at loader (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (sessionID_reducer.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at loader (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at loader (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (test_helper.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at loader (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:311:3
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:310:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my_app@1.0.0 test: `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_app@1.0.0 test script 'mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the my_app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my_app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my_app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app\npm-debug.log`
```

And here's my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "dev": "nodemon server/server.js"
  }
```

To be honest I'm not entirely sure what's going on here. I just copied some code from the package.json of a boiler plate that has the tests running fine. I know it's using the test_helper.js code that I wrote but I'm not sure what else it's doing. Also finally here's the npm debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.1
3 info using node@v4.4.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info pretest my_app@1.0.0
6 info test my_app@1.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info my_app@1.0.0 Failed to exec test script
9 verbose stack Error: my_app@1.0.0 test: `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid my_app@1.0.0
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\name\Desktop\my_app
12 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
13 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
14 error node v4.4.3
15 error npm  v2.15.1
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error my_app@1.0.0 test: `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the my_app@1.0.0 test script 'mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the my_app package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs my_app
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls my_app
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever URL is being passed to socket.io is probably `undefined`.
Can you share whatever code uses socket.io? It might look something like:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost');
```

You would receive that error if 'http://localhost' in that code was `undefined`

Comment: Since we're using React, we're using ES6 syntax. This is what it looks like `import io from 'socket.io-client'; var socket= io();` I made it `var socket = io('http://localhost')` and now it works, thanks! Since we're planning on deploying it, would we have have to change it or can we keep it?

Comment: I suppose it depends what you are using socket.io for. That would the the URL of whatever you are opening a web socket to.